# How to pretend that an API request is is being sent from Firefox?

Tags: node.js, firefox, cookies, fetch-api, java-http-client

I'm implementing an app to fetch requests from a website API that seems to be protected by Cloudfare. When I make requests to the API using Java HttpClient framework, I get the following response (I've piped the response to an html file, and opened it in browser)

[image]

It's worth noting that when I make the same request using NodeJS fetch method, I still get the same response, but when I make the request in Firefox console using Javascript fetch method, there's no error, the response is valid and there's no problem. I thought that maybe my app should somehow pretend that the request is being sent from Firefox (or any other browser). But I don't know how to do that. Here is a sample code of what I'm trying to do:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.net.http.*;
import java.time.Duration;

public class HttpClientTest1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CookieManager cm = new CookieManager();
        cm.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
        CookieHandler.setDefault(cm);

        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .cookieHandler(cm)
                .followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.ALWAYS)
                .build();

        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .GET()
                .uri(new URI("https://api.doggy.market/listings/nfts/minidoges?sortBy=price&sortOrder=asc&offset=0&limit=30"))
                .header("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8")
                .header("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.5")
                .header("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "document")
                .header("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "navigate")
                .header("Sec-Fetch-Site", "none")
                .header("Sec-Fetch-User", "?1")
                .header("TE", "trailers")
                .header("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1")
                .header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0")
                .build();

        HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        System.out.println(response.statusCode());
        System.out.println(response.body());
    }
}
```

What's wrong with my request? What's missing that I need to consider? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Open the Network tab of your web-browser's web tool, navigate to the request and see what the exact URL was, what were the parameters sent to it either via GET or POST and check the request headers as well. Compare these things to the request that you are sending and eliminate the differences. In the meantime keep an eye on the server logs for errors there and see what the errors are if you send your request from NodeJS.

Comment: And please don't forget about CORS and pre-flight requests

Comment: @LajosArpad I've done all things you mentioned. I've compared all of the headers with that of the browser. But I still get the same error. I can't understant what's wrong with my request.

Comment: @Anatoly Can you explain more please?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS I meant if you mimic a browser then you need to mimic CORS headers and pre-flight requests in general. Isn't it?